# Need C# regex to parse the php define() function value.

Tags: c#, regex

```
 define('CONST1', 'value'   );
define   (CONST2, 'value2');
define(   'CONST3', time());
  define('define', 'define');
    define("test", VALUE4);
define('const5', //

'weird declaration'
)    ;
define('CONST7', 3.14);
define ( /* comment */ 'foo', 'bar');
$defn = 'blah';
define($defn, 'foo');
define( 'CONST4', define('CONST5', 6));
```

need c# regex to get these values of constants in c#. This is just string in c# or file content. i need to parse it and get the constants and values in c#.

Comment: I need a Ferrari, but if I show no effort to work for one, do I deserve it?

Comment: man i already have done so much work on it. but its useless to post here. because its not working. if you don't have the solution please don't post silly replies. Don't waste time. i wonder you are a free man who has nothing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = input.Replace("\r", "").input("\n", "");
var pattern = @"define\((.*?)\)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
}
```

this solves the issue. input is the variable which contain the string. contain the php code with define("abc", "xyz");